# Locker size at Frankfurt (Main) Hbf

Tags: germany, luggage-storage, train-stations, frankfurt

I have 2 big luggage (size no. 2) and 1 travelling bag (flight cabin size).   Can I use 1 locker to fit them all?  Otherwise I will pack into only 2 luggages .
Thanks!

Comment: How big is your luggage?

Comment: Depends on the size of the lockers and the size/how full the bags are?

Comment: Lockers are not that expensive, so even if you would need two lockers, it's no big deal.

Answer (score 2):

The dimensions of the lockers are as follows.

- Small locker: 420 x 800 x 273 mm (~ 90L)
- Large locker: 615 x 930 x 472 mm (~ 270L)

(https://community.bahn.de/questions/1582543-schliessfacher-frankfurt-hauptbahnhof-aktuelle-preise - please note that this information is from 2018)

If your bags can be arranged into that volume, then you should be fine.